# Displaying "current" key in jq

Tags: jq

I have a dictionary keyed on usernames, like:

```json
"userinfo": { "alice": { "key1": 1, "key2": 2}, "bob": { "key1": 11, "key2": 22}, ... }
```

I want to display tabular text of the username and some values.

```
alice 1 2
bob 11 22
```

It's easy enough to get the usernames into the first column OR to pull the values out (`.info[]|[.key1,.key2]`) into the later columns, but I can't figure out how to get both the usernames and the values under them in the same `jq` command.  I am trying to avoid doing something silly like running `jq` multiple times and pasting the output.

Answer (score 11):

You can use following command to do it:

```bash
jq -r '.userinfo | to_entries[] | [.key, .value.key1, .value.key2] | @tsv'
```

You first convert the data to `entries` so you can reference them, then make a `list` with your values and at the end you convert it into a `tab-seperated-values` output with the `@tsv` operator. If you want it to be another format, you can read more about it [here](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#format-strings-and-escaping).

Also use the `-r` flag to get raw output, otherwise you would get the `"\t"` character :)

---

Comment from @[0stone0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/339347):
If you have an unknown number of key*'s, you can use `[ .key, .value[] ]` to get them all

Comment: Amazing!  Thank you.  That is exactly what I need, I was unfamiliar with to_entries[] but it is going to be handy for a lot of odd cases.

Comment: Yeah `jq` is a really really powerful tool. It's like learning a whole new programming language. Whenever I think I learned everything about it there are still some new things :)

Answer (score 7):

```bash
$ jq -r '.userinfo | keys[] as $k | [ $k, .[$k][] ] | @tsv' file
alice   1       2
bob     11      22
```

This assumes that the input in `file` is a valid JSON document, such as

```json
{
  "userinfo": {
    "alice": {
      "key1": 1,
      "key2": 2
    },
    "bob": {
      "key1": 11,
      "key2": 22
    }
  }
}
```

The `jq` expression picks out the `userinfo` top-level object and then iterates over the keys of this object, with each key being assigned to the internal variable `$k`. It is specifically the `[]` of `keys[]` that causes the looping over all the keys (usernames).

For each iteration, the array `[ $k, .[$k][] ]` is constructed, i.e. an array consisting of the key itself followed by the values in the `userinfo` object associated with that particular key (regardless of what the keys under `.[$k]` might be or how many there may be, i.e. we ignore the keys `key1` and `key2` themselves).

The constructed array is then passed through the `@tsv` operator which outputs it as a tab-delimited record.

For this to make any sense, we assume that the keys are ordered the same way for each object under `userinfo`.  If that's not the case, you may want to sort the keys by passing the data through `jq -S .` first.  If sub-objects have a varying set of keys (some may have a `key3` and others may lack `key1`), then the output is still unlikely to make sense as you have no header on the fields in the output and no indication that a key is missing in an object.

We can take care of generating headers for each field based on the key names in the sub-objects (and using `name` as the header for the username field) with a somewhat more complicated `jq` expression:

```
(
    [.userinfo[] | keys[]] | unique
) as $h |

# This creates the header using "name" and the unique keys
# from each sub-object:
[ "name", $h[] ],

# Now we need a "double loop" over each user object and
# the unique keys (in $h) that we extracted previously,
# basically: for each user, create an array consisting of 
# the username and the value for each of the keys
# (the inner loop):
[
    .userinfo as $u | 
    $u | 

    # Outer loop:
    keys[] as $k | 
    [
        # The username:
        $k,
        # Inner loop over the $h array, extracting
        # either useful data or nothing depending on
        # whether the key exists in this object.
        ($h[] | $u[$k][.])
  ]
]
| @tsv
```

Example input with unsorted and missing/extra keys:

```json
{
  "userinfo": {
    "alice": {
      "key2": 2,
      "key1": 1
    },
    "bob": {
      "key1": 11,
      "key2": 22
    },
    "mallory": {
      "key1": 111,
      "key3": 333
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
name    key1    key2    key3
alice   1       2
bob     11      22
mallory 111             333
```